# Web-based "snap-circuits" platform and course

Tags: design

Looking for a web-based version of "[Snap Circuits SC-300](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000683A4)" with related courses/projects, and possibly even has some sort of skill/knowledge based leveling and reporting in between the courses/projects/topics.

Comment: If you have enough money, just buy the kit. Electronics is making things, you have to learn the smell of solder flux smoke  and not to breathe it :) By the way, I bought one of these to my friend's little brother and he loved it.

Comment: @abdullah kahraman: Thanks, I have the kit, and in fact know of [an example of a virtual “snap-circuits” platform](http://www.dcaclab.com/en/lab/), but it appears to lack the courses/projects and related skill/knowledge based leveling and reporting. As for smelling stuff, guessing most systems are designed in tested within a computer, not in the real world first; have no idea though, just a guess.

Comment: It depends on the age and the level of knowledge and experience on electronics. However, if you have experimented with the kit, then I would suggest you to move on to real things. You should search for books or resources that are suitable to you in this manner. If you have any question in the learning process, Google and StackExchange are great.

Comment: Yes, systems are designed in with the help of a computer, however, this is for system designers that are experienced and know stuff. It is hard to learn on the computer and with the internet, that a 1/4 watt resistor will heat up if you give it 1 watt. Of course this depends on lots of things, but you get the vibe I guess?

Comment: @abdullah kahraman: Element response to the system design, or errors in the system design, should be easy to notice, and yes, I understand/agree with your point, though just hoping your point doesn't become the answer, and that if someone is aware of a better electronics simulation platform with related courseware/testings/reporting that someone will point it out.

Comment: Ah no, this is just a comment. I hope you will find your answers.

Comment: @abdullah kahraman: Main thing is that I ran across the example I linked to yesterday, was aware of "Snap Circuits SC-300" (and have used it to teach) and wondering if there was a better version of it. Just ran across Electronics.SE today, a figured I'd ask.

Answer (score 2):

[Circuit Lab](https://www.circuitlab.com/) may meet your needs. It is an online simulator. They also have some sample circuits.

Comment: +1 @Brian Carlton: Yes, looks nice, and there are sample circuits. Guessing you're unaware of this, but figure it wouldn't hurt to ask. Are you aware of any courseware that would map to the features provided by Circuit Lab that would feature a basic to advance problem sets, with some sort of reporting mechanism? Again, thanks, it's a great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

tldr; 
design your own equivalent components to have snap-circuits visuals using an online electronics simulator e.g. https://library.io/ or https://dcaclab.com/en/home

Its been 7 years, but someone else might find this useful.  I think there is great merit in what you ask, not so much for adults more for children and teenagers.
Imagine you already have a snap circuits kit and some software that simulates the circuits but also looks exactly like the snap circuit components in front of you.

You can get hold of the instructions, create the project on the screen by dragging and dropping stuff, see it work and then do the same thing in the real world and see it work.  What a visceral experience and it directly relates what is going on on the screen to the real world.  You would be able to try more on the computer, do you want 10 leds instead of one, no problem, do you want 1000, also no problem, do you want transistors as well as resistors, capacitors and batteries, ICs, op-amps, multivibrators, coils, and so on.  Want to see it in slow motion, where the current is flowing, voltages at specific points its all possible in the software and it is all connected to the real world via the same thing on the screen as you have in front of you.

From an educational perspective, you can really explain what is going on along side the design on the screen as well as having them build it and see the led light or whatever.

And then they can move on to more sophisticated things at their own pace, because once you have built it once online everyone can access it. ... At their own pace ... whenever they want   ....in their pyjamas on a Saturday morning or whatever.

From an implementation point of view, I cannot see anything that does exactly that, but what I can see is a number of on-line and free circuit design simulators that allow you to create your own libraries and components including the visuals.  You could use those to create a snap-circuits library that looked just like the physical real world components and get what you want.  I may even do it myself time permitting (always time permitting) and will post an update if I do.  Similarly this is not restricted to snao circuits it applies to breadboards (already exist), arduino (already exist), raspberry pi (probably exist), lego robotics (already exist) and so on.

The simulators I found that might do the trick are:
https://library.io/
https://dcaclab.com/en/home

Comment: +1 to david's comment. Right now (March 2020) there are thousands of students moving from physical classrooms to online learning. I could assemble a circuit for middle school students on a zoom video, but it gives them nothing to do and they don't all have circuits.   Being able to assign them online simulator tasks would at least let them play with design, and maybe see some sort of output. (maybe the fan would spin, etc.)  In any case, this appears to still be a missing resource.  Maybe necessity will be the father of invention once again and someone will follow your advice.